# How to dereference and call a function of a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Lets say we have this struct:

```
typedef struct foo {
   int (*func)(char *param);
} foo;
```

and we have this prototype:

```
void bar(foo *f){
  char *t = something
  int a = f->func(t)
  do stuff with a
}
```

but this gives a segfault when initializing int a. I also tried `int a = f->func(t)` but this also leads to a segfault

I call bar by

```
foo *baz = malloc(sizeof(foo));
baz->func = &somefunction;
bar((foo *) &baz);
```

Comment: You must *initialise* the `struct` member like any other before using it.

Comment: `foo baz = initializing it`. There's your problem. But more seriously, show us the actual code as we cannot point out problems in code we can't see. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I do initialize it. I edited my post

Comment: The most important part of the code is the part you're glossing over.  In other words, what is "initializing it" exactly?

Comment: Please show *actual code*, the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem. `void bar(foo *f);` will not compile.

Comment: Now you are just making up random code. `foo` is not a function pointer type. For the fourth time - show us the actual code as a minimal reproducible example - that is, construct a simple complete example that we can copy and run for ourselves to see the problem.

Comment: Re the latest edit, that won't even compile. `foo baz = malloc(sizeof(foo))` should be `struct foo baz = malloc(sizeof( struct foo));`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
     int (*func)( const char *param );
};


void bar( struct foo *f)
{
    int i = f->func( "123" );

    printf( "i = %i\n", i );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct foo f = { atoi };

    bar( &f );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
123
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
     int (*func)( const char *param );
};


void bar( struct foo *f)
{
    int i = f->func( "123" );

    printf( "i = %i\n", i );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct foo *f = malloc( sizeof( struct foo ) );
    f->func = atoi;

    bar( f );

    free( f );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same as accessing any other members of the structures

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct _ms
{
    int (*hello)(int);
    int (*bye)(int);
    struct _ms *ms;
}mystruct_t;

int h(int x) 
{
    return printf("Hello %d\n", x);
}

int g(int x) 
{
    return printf("Bye %d\n", x);
}

void call(mystruct_t *str)
{ 
    int charsprinted;
    charsprinted = str -> hello(10);
    charsprinted += str -> bye(20);

    charsprinted = str -> ms -> hello(50);
    charsprinted += str -> ms -> bye(50);


    printf("Call: printd %d chars\n", charsprinted);
}

int main()
{
    mystruct_t str1 = {.hello = h, .bye = g};
    mystruct_t str = {.hello = h, .bye = g, .ms = &str1};

    call(&str);

    str.hello(100);
    str.bye(1000);
    str.ms -> hello(2000);
    str.ms -> bye(2000);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hBFpGC